# JSON object parse issue on react

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string, reactjs

```
json = "{ elements: [ {type: 'radiogroup', choices: ['Yes','No','Maybe','Never'], isRequired: true, name: 'Test_01', title: 'Do you like ice cream?' }],showQuestionNumbers: 'off'}";  
   json = JSON.stringify(json);
   model = new Model(json);
```

it dosen't recognise the json object when it have quotes on

```
 var json = "{ elements: [ {type: 'radiogroup', choices: ['Yes','No','Maybe','Never'], isRequired: true, name: 'Test_01', title: 'Do you like ice cream?' }],showQuestionNumbers: 'off'}";
```

it works when removes quotes

```
   json = { elements: [ {type: 'radiogroup', choices: ['Yes','No','Maybe','Never'], isRequired: true, name: 'Test_01', title: 'Do you like ice cream?' }],showQuestionNumbers: 'off'};
```

I have tried JSON.parse(json); it dosen't work, would anyone please suggest solution, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have JSON in a string, then you should do `JSON.parse`, not `JSON.stringify`.

Also, single quotes are invalid in JSON, so always use double-quotes for that.

```
// I fixed the JSON
var json = '{ elements: [ {type: "radiogroup", choices: ["Yes","No","Maybe","Never"], isRequired: true, name: "Test_01", title: "Do you like ice cream?" }],showQuestionNumbers: "off"}';
// The thing you would expect
var obj = JSON.parse(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are trying to stringify a string no the object remove " " and it would become object and then try JSON.stringify and JSON.parse is not working because the data is not in proper JSON string format. For example:

var object = '{"e":"a"}';
Then use JSON.parse(object); 
Which will convert your string in object.